# Simple selfwritten JobScheduler causes deadlock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, deadlock

Im writing my own JobScheduler for learning purposes. The idea is pretty simple, it starts n threads, pulls Jobs/Task from a concurrent queue, processes them and once finished it will notify a Event so the mainthread can wait for it to finish ( if he wants ).

The thread loop looks like this...

```cs
    internal long ItemCount;  // The amount of jobs to process
    internal ManualResetEventSlim Event { get; set; }  // Event to notify worker threads for new items 
    internal ConcurrentQueue<JobMeta> Jobs { get; set; }  // Jobs

    private void Loop(CancellationToken token) {
        
        Loop:

        // Break if cancellation is requested
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        
        // Make threads wait, the event tells them when new jobs arrived
        Event.Wait(token);
        if (Jobs.TryDequeue(out var jobMeta)) {  // Concurrent, dequeue one at a time

            // Make other threads wait once no more items are in the queue
            if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref ItemCount) == 0) Event.Reset();

            jobMeta.Job.Execute();      // Execute job
            jobMeta.JobHandle.Set(); // ManualResetEvent.Set to notify the main e.g.
        }
        goto Loop;
    }

    // Notify threads about new arrived jobs 
    public void NotifyThreads() {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref ItemCount, Jobs.Count);  // Set ItemCount
        Event.Set();  // Notify
    }

    // Enqueues new job
    public JobHandle Schedule(IJob job) {

        var handle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var jobMeta = new JobMeta{ JobHandle = handle, Job = job};
        Jobs.Enqueue(jobMeta);
        return handle;
    }
```

However sometimes this causes a deadlock if i do something like this :

```cs
var jobHandle = threadScheduler.Schedule(myJob);  // JobHandle is a ManualResetEvent
threadScheduler.NotifyThreads();

for(var index = 0; index < 10000; index++){
   
   var otherJobHandle = threadScheduler.Schedule(otherJob);
   threadScheduler.NotifyThreads();
   otherJobHandle.Wait();
}

jobHandle.Wait();  // Deadlock sometimes...
```

Why could this cause a deadlock ? Wheres the logic issue ? And how would a normal JobScheduler look like ( since i cant find any good informations about this topic in general ) ?

Glad for any help !

Comment: What you are trying to do can be greatly simplified by using the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class, instead of messing around with low-level `ManualResetEventSlim`s and `ConcurrentQueue<T>`s.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks ! However i also get a deadlock with a blocking collection... so i guess that part is not the problem :/

Comment: It is hard to say where is the problem as you didn't provide MVCE ... fx `Schedule` returns `JobHandle` (`public JobHandle Schedule(IJob job)` but you are returning  `ManualResetEvent` ... Who knows what other code is missing/changed here

Comment: Have you tried replacing all three state fields (`long ItemCount`, `ManualResetEventSlim Event` and `ConcurrentQueue<JobMeta> Jobs`) with a single `BlockingCollection<JobMeta>`, and you are still getting deadlocks?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Exactly... and its getting more strange. Only when i run it as release... as debug my current code and the modified version with a blockingcollection do work flawless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your last snippet could cause a deadlock, because `jobHandle` is first enqueued, its handle should already be set.

---

I can find 2 problems in your implemention. First is this line:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref ItemCount, Jobs.Count);
```

Think about if the code is executed in the following order:

```
                         //queue.count = 1
1. Jobs.TryDequeue       //queue.count = 0
2. Interlocked.Exchange  //ItemCount = 0
3. Interlocked.Decrement //ItemCount = -1
```

`ItemCount` is decreased twice. So what you should do is increase `ItemCount` while a job is enqueued.

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref ItemCount);
Jobs.Enqueue(jobMeta);
```

---

The second problem is in the loop, think about this code execution order:

```
1. Jobs.TryDequeue
2. Interlocked.Decrement
  3. Interlocked.Increment
  3. Jobs.Enqueue
  3. Event.Set
4. Event.Reset
```

In the end the state of the wait handle is unset, it can cause a deadlock because your attempt is the handle should be set after enqueueing a job. In such case you need run the code in a reversed order:

```
1. Jobs.TryDequeue
2. Event.Reset // anyway reset the handle
3. if(Interlocked.Decrement > 0)
      Event.Set
```

With this approach, whenever a job is enqueued before `Interlocked.Decrement` or not, the state of the wait handle is correct.

---

Above approach maybe is not efficient enough because we need toggle the wait handle in each loop, I suggest you to add a while-loop for the queue:

```
int count = 0;
while(Jobs.TryDequeue(out var jobMeta)) {
    ++count;
    ...
}

if(count > 0) {
    Event.Reset();
    if(Interlocked.Add(ref ItemCount, -count) > 0)
        Event.Set();
}
```